# "The type or namespace name 'Models' could not be found" with "using"

Tags: c#

I moved my Models classes to a dll file and I try to use it form another project with "using":

```
using MyApp.Library;

    //...
    var db = new Models.Database.MyDatabaseEntities();
    //...
```

But I get the error:
`The type or namespace name 'Models' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

If I use it like this:

```
    var db = new MyApp.Library.Models.Database.MyDatabaseEntities();
```

It seems to work. But I want to use "using" since I will need to use Models a lot. Why I cant use "using"? Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you add reference?(Right click the project node)

Comment: Yes I did, and it works with second code sample, so the reference is ok

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** I Suspect that you have multiple Namespaces which refer to `Model` class.

**Solution :**

**1.** You can avoid this ambiguity by using `FullyQulaifiedNameSpace` as below:

```
var db = new MyApp.Library.Models.Database.MyDatabaseEntities();
```

**2.** You can use [Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) to avoid this ambiguity.

Try This:

```
using mymodel = MyApp.Library;

var db = new mymodel.Models.Database.MyDatabaseEntities();
```

Comment: The "solution" is working but I don't think the "problem" is correct. Why I would get "could not be found" error if its ambiguous (it says not found on "Models"). Would like to know the real problem.